# How to fix: error report "Permission Error(13,'Access denied')" on Chrome GPU process crash?

Tags: permissions, google-chrome, bug-reporting, error-handling

**UPDATE**

To avoid `Chrome GPU process` crashes I recommend `xorg` graphics drivers instead of any `flgrx`, even own-build one. Could be installed e.g. from `Additional Drivers` app.

I'm not having any more crashes, neither settings for screen brightness or functionality of WiFi <kbd>fn</kbd> key though...

---

I am getting Chrome crashes that can not be reported (as I understand 'permission error'). These are GPU process crashes while no blacklist overriding and default `chrome://flags`.

What I want to know is **how to enable error report** for this problem. Use sudo or group somewhere, I don't know...

---

Screenshot:

[image]

---

Would be nice to also know how to avoid those crashes.

---

EDIT: System spec.

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64
Chrome 36.0.1985.125
Proc / graphics: AMD E2-1800 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2
^ driven by fglrx-updates package / VESA HONDO
```

---

EDIT2: `chrome://gpu` default flags (as html pages):

Before crash
https://c11fbf01d63d06741cc45a90608f0e7d75f13312.googledrive.com/host/0B9qkeujf78R0ZklvUVloUUxlejA/gpu_before-crash_default-flags.html

After crash
https://c11fbf01d63d06741cc45a90608f0e7d75f13312.googledrive.com/host/0B9qkeujf78R0ZklvUVloUUxlejA/gpu_after-crash_default-flags.html

---

Actually I see the same `Permission error` for `Archive Manager` crash.

Comment: Bugs in Google Chrome shouldn't be reported to Ubuntu, since it's not managed in any way by Ubuntu. Bugs should be reported to Google.

Comment: What about 'archive manager' crash with the same `Permission Error`? And how do I generate nice error report for Google?

Comment: Archive Manager is indeed part of Ubuntu, so there's a valid error there. As for Chrome crashes, I think there's an option to automatically submit bug reports in the options, but you can also manually file a bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list). (not the "Permission Error" part, of course, but the crash itself)

Comment: Thanks. But still I take it as the Ubuntu error reporting is disabled on my system.

Comment: See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#How_to_enable_apport) for enabling the error reporting, but my guess is that it is already enabled, since you are seeing that window.

Comment: I am seeing this exact same thing in Xubuntu 14.04. I tried reporting a bug on Thunar (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/+bug/1367381) using "ubuntu-bug Thunar" and it popped up a grey window saying "permission error 13: access denied". So, this bug is not related to whether you try to report bugs for chrome or for native packages. This needs a fix.